# Old front audio headers

Tags: audio, jumper

A friend recently asked me to diagnose his PC (the PSU was faulty), but that's beside the point. I foolishly disconnected the front audio headers before checking the way they were connected, and now I can't wrap my head around how I should connect them. First time I am seeing those:

[image]

The labels on those headers are:

- **MIC IN** x2
- **EAR L** x2
- **GND** x2 (ground)
- **EAR R** x2

The header on the motherboard is an **AAFP**.
Suppose I go with the legacy option. So do I connect:

- **MIC IN** to **MIC2**?
- **EAR L** to **Line Out_L**?
- **EAR R** to **Line Out_R**?
- **GND** to **AGND**?

If so, then what should I connect to **MICPWR**?
I assume **NC** stands for **No Connection**?
And what do I do with the remaining jumpers? (There are two of each!)

Comment: You'll need to know where they connect on the motherboard. The motherboard manual should tell you.

Comment: The header on the motherboard should be labelled in the same was as the labelling on the connectors in your hand.

Comment: @spikey_richie, the manual is the first thing I looked into, after was google, but they are completely different!

Comment: OK, your question didn't say that hence I explored the avenue below.

Answer (score 2):

Excuse the poor image quality, but you're looking for something like this:

[image]

Note the etched image underneath the pins, which show what goes where. Plug the connectors onto the relevant pins, observing polarity.

For best results, consult the motherboard manual.

**Edit - updated for your motherboard model**

[image]

Comment: The F_PANEL header is for power and reset switches and their LEDs. And the case also has a SPEAKER header. The motherboard is an Asus B85M-G, and the only audio header I see is the AAFP header, which has labels completely different to the ones on the case headers, not to mention that, every header is doubled, see the image and list in the question

Comment: They're doubled as one is for a legacy device controller. I would use the Legacy AC'97.